# Overlapping ranges between lists in Scala

Tags: list, scala

Considering the following two Lists in Scala:

```
l1: List(List(4,6), List(17,20), List(27))
l2: List(1,6,11,16,26,30)
```

I want first to create a new list from the second list l2

```
l3: List(List(1,5), List(6,10), List(11,15), List(16,25), List(26,29), List(30))
```

After that I want to find the overlapping intervals between the two lists (l1 and l3)
The output must be:

```
List(List(4,5), List(6), list(17,20) list(27))
```

I have found this to verify if there is an ovelap between two lists

```
def overlaps(x:List[Int],y:List[Int]) = (x contains y.lift(0)) || (y contains x.lift(0))
```

But I don't know how to extend this to resolve my problem.
If there is any optimal way to find this result without creating the list l3, it will be possibe for me.

Comment: Is it a correct observation that `l1` contains only lists with 1 or 2 elements? Would it not be a better fit to use tuples instead? `l1: List((4,6), (17,20), (27, Integer.MAX_VALUE))` as I understand these are the intervals you want to represent.

Comment: Yes these are intervals, I am new user of Scala, how can I convert the List of Lists to a List of tuples?

Comment: Convert: `l1.zipWithIndex.map(list => list match {case (_, List(v1, v2)) => (v1, v2); case (0, List(v1)) => (Integer.MIN_VALUE, v1); case (index, List(v1)) => if (index == l1.length) (v1, Integer.MAX_VALUE) else (v1, v1)})` or something similar. Your overlap code is wrong when used for intervals you described.

Comment: Any solution to my problem?

Comment: It is not too hard, you can do that, though I think it is too broad for this site. This is not a free coding site.

Comment: Could you please update your question with: `sample input`, `signature of desired function`, and then `expected output`? Example: `sample input: 1`, `signature of function: Int => Int`, `expected output: 2`, which would have an answer of `def add1(x: Int): Int = x + 1`